# What Inverse kinematics technique does the legacy IK solver use?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

There are different IK techniques like FABRIK, CCD, Jacobian inverse technique etc. Does anybody know which one Blender's legacy solver uses?

Comment: Which one do you mean by "legacy solver", the one called "Standard"?

Comment: @rjg Yes the standard one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** The legacy solver uses Jacobian IK.

I'm not very familiar with the IK implementation, but here is what I've found out from Blender's source.

`source/blender/ikplugin/intern/iksolver_plugin.c` contains (parts of) the code that make up the legacy solver. In this code `iksolver_execute_tree()` calls `execute_posetree()` which creates the IK solver using `IK_CreateSolver()`. This results in the creation of instance of `IK_QSolver`. This object contains an instance of `IK_QJacobianSolve` which is used when `execute_posetree()` calls `IK_Solve` and passes `IK_QSolver` as argument.

This means the solver uses Jacobian IK. The actual implementation of the solver can be found in `intern/iksolver/intern/IK_QJacobianSolver.cpp`.